# INNERHTML no es una función

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto con vue js en quasar y estoy creando una función para exportar el contenido de mi página a PDF

este es el código de la función:

```
downloadPDF() {
        
            const doc = new jsPDF();
            const contentHtml = this.$refs.content.innerHTML;
            doc.fromHTML(contentHtml, 15, 15, {
              width: 170
            });
            doc.save("sample.pdf");
        },
```

y este es mi archivo vue en donde a mi tepmlate le agregué una etiqueta "content"

```
<template ref="content">
  <div>
    <q-page class="centrar-contenido">
      <div  class="container q-py-md q-px-lg q-mb-xs contenedorDatos" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, #F4EBE910 0%, #F1E8DE 100%)">
          <div class="row">
                <q-btn class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 q-pr-xl contenedorVisualizacion">
                  <b @click="abrirModalCorto" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 q-py-lg">
                    <div></div>
                    <div style="color:#DA8800;font-size: 15px;">Carga Financiera Corto Plazo: {{porcentajeCortoPlazo}}%</div>
                  </b>
                </q-btn>
                <q-btn class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 q-pl-md q-pr-md contenedorVisualizacion">
                  <b @click="abrirModalLargo" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 q-py-lg">
                    <div></div>
                    <div style="color:#DA8800;font-size: 15px;">Carga Financiera Largo Plazo: {{porcentajeLargoPlazo}}%</div>
                  </b>
                </q-btn>
                <q-btn class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 q-pl-xl contenedorVisualizacion">
                  <b @click="abrirModalTotal" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12  q-py-lg">
                    <div></div>
                    <div style="color:#DA8800;font-size: 15px;">Carga Financiera Total: {{porcentajeFinancieraTotal}}%</div>
                  </b> 
                </q-btn>
            </div>
        </div>
```

AL momento de ejecutar esta función esta me devuelve un "INNERHTML is not function", si me pudieran ayudar o como utilizar bien esta librería, lo que deseo es que el contenido de mi página se pueda exportar a pdf

Answer (score 0):

Intenta mover **ref** a tu div más cercano. También asegurate de cerrar correctamente las etiquetas HTML.

```html
<template>
    <div ref="content">
      <q-page class="centrar-contenido">
        <div  class="container q-py-md q-px-lg q-mb-xs contenedorDatos" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, #F4EBE910 0%, #F1E8DE 100%)">
            <div class="row">
                  <q-btn class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 q-pr-xl contenedorVisualizacion">
                    <b @click="abrirModalCorto" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 q-py-lg">
                      <div></div>
                      <div style="color:#DA8800;font-size: 15px;">Carga Financiera Corto Plazo: {{porcentajeCortoPlazo}}%</div>
                    </b>
                  </q-btn>
                  <q-btn class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 q-pl-md q-pr-md contenedorVisualizacion">
                    <b @click="abrirModalLargo" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 q-py-lg">
                      <div></div>
                      <div style="color:#DA8800;font-size: 15px;">Carga Financiera Largo Plazo: {{porcentajeLargoPlazo}}%</div>
                    </b>
                  </q-btn>
                  <q-btn class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 q-pl-xl contenedorVisualizacion">
                    <b @click="abrirModalTotal" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12  q-py-lg">
                      <div></div>
                      <div style="color:#DA8800;font-size: 15px;">Carga Financiera Total: {{porcentajeFinancieraTotal}}%</div>
                    </b>
                  </q-btn>
              </div>
          </div>
      </q-page>
    </div>
</template>
```